# How to remove the Request-Context header in an Azure Functions v2 response

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

In an Azure Functions v2 app, among the headers that a client receives there is:

```
Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:<UUID>
```

I understand that this header is used to correlate requests in Application Insights from apps that use different instrumentation keys, which is not my case.

Is it possible to remove the Request-Context header?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible through Application Insights collection options (in host.json)

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "httpAutoCollectionOptions": {
        "enableResponseHeaderInjection" : false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removeServerHeader="true"?

https://github.com/alrod/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/commit/a32109868f10457688d14e35ff4090eabec372ca

Comment: Thanks @Kamran. Please can you expand on how to apply that setting in an Azure Functions? It seems that configuration via web.config is not possible in Az Fun.